# Bulk administration using csv import to remove device from Azure AD list

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, csv, import-csv

I am trying to create a PowerShell script to cleanup Azure AD devices.
I figured I should probably find a combination of these:

```
Get-MsolDevice -all | select-object -Property Enabled, DeviceId, DisplayName, DeviceTrustType, ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp | export-csv C:\Temp\devicelist-summary.csv
```

and

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\devicelist-summary.csv' | ForEach-Object {}
```

and

```
Remove-MsolDevice -DeviceId “device_ID_number” -Force
```

Then ultimately depending on ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp I would remove them from the Azure AD device list.
Unfortunately I have few knowledge in coding so I am kind of stuck, I tried my best but it would be very helpful is someone could help me. 
I think I am close to something here.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you logged on and do you receive the devices when running Get-MsolDevice?

If you do, you might want to do something like:

```bsh
Get-MsolDevice -all | Where-Object {$_.ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp -gt $(Get-Date).AddDays(-180)} | Foreach-Object {Remove-MsolDevice -DeviceId $_.DeviceId -Force}
```

This saves you from creating a CSV file.

You might want to split the one-liner up in a few steps and then add a log on all the devices you delete.

Comment: Hey Axel thank you for your response.

I am logged indeed and receive the device list when running Get-MsolDevice.
It seems easier to do it lit this with the date set to 180, thank you so much !